# How to parse stock data from objects into an array

Tags: javascript, algorithm, reactjs, visualization

I am using the Recharts library to plot some stock market data. However, the simple line chart requires a very strict data structure like so

```
{name: 'Page A', uv: 4000, pv: 2400, amt: 2400}
```

I have data that looks like this

```
Object
AAPL:Array[4]
0:Object
adjClose:53.509768
close:411.23
date:"2012-01-02T18:30:00.000Z"
high:412.499989
low:408.999989
open:409.399998
symbol:"AAPL"
volume:75555200
__proto__:Object
1:Object
2:Object
3:Object
length:4
__proto__:Array[0]
GOOGL:Array[4]
TSLA:Array[4]
```

where each object for a specific ticker represents one day for that ticker. It seems like I need to go from that to a data structure like this

```
data=[
    {date: 'Jan 12, 2012', AAPL: {open: 12, close: 15}, TSLA: {open: 15, close: 21}, GOOGL: {open: 125, close: 21}}, 
    {date: 'Jan 13, 2012', AAPL: {open: 15, close: 12}, TSLA: {open: 21, close: 155}, GOOGL: {open: 21, close: 25}}
    ...
    ...
    ...
];
```

I am still not entirely sure that Recharts will plot the data the way I want even this way, but it seems the most likely option.

Just to clarify, the way I want it plotted is a separate line chart for each ticker on the same chart element

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can iterate through each symbol and then build the data object using a simple loop, with a sub loop into each symbol. This will assume each symbol contains identical arrays for the same dates.

```
// result object
let result = [];

// get the ticker list from the object keys
const tickers = Object.keys(yourDataObject);

// get number of days for first ticker by looking at it's array length
const days = yourDataObject[tickers[0]].length;

// iterate through the days to parse the data
for (let i = 0; i < days; i++) {
  // initiate row data with date of the first symbol
  let rowData = {
    date: new Date(yourDataObject[tickers[0]][i]).toLocaleDateString(),
  }
  // iterate through the tickers for that day
  symbols.forEach(symbol => {
    const tickerDayData = yourDataObject[symbol][i];
    rowData[ticker] = {
      open: ~~tickerDayData.open, // using ~~ to get the int value, you could round if you'd prefer
      close: ~~tickerDayData.close,
    };
  });
  // add to main result array
  result.push(rowData);
}
```

If you provided actual data we could run this in the console for testing.

Comment: Hey, that worked a charm. Thanks! 
Yeah, sorry about not providing actual data. I just pulled that data from an api for an app I'm writing, so I wasn't sure how to put up the original data on here.

Comment: Great, glad to hear. Hope this helps broaden your understanding of JS.